# SmartImageView and Custom ListAdapter - First few items' imageViews not drawing?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview, android-arrayadapter

I need some help with a ListView.

**Background:**

I've created a ListAdapter that extends ArrayAdapter -

Each of the items in the list has 2 [SmartImageView's](http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/) and I fetch the URL names in an asynctask  and set them with:  image1.setImageURL(someURL).

I also make use of view tags with a scoreHolder. My asynctask works with a listener called onURLSFullyFetched - So I'm only setting the [SmartImageView's](http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/) when I'm done fetching the URLS.

List items are based on an array of scoreData and I construct a String array images[] to match how many elements are in scoreData.

In my getView() when I populate the images I do the following:
 1. Check if images[position] is null - if it is, call an asynctask task to fetch image urls, and save the result into images[position] and set the image holders with:

```
scoreHolder.image1.setImageUrl(URLS[1]);                                
scoreHolder.image2.setImageUrl(RLS[0]);
```

2. if images[position is not null, I simply set scoreHolder images based on images[position].

**Problem:**

Everything works well except when I load the list view, every item that is "displayed" (visible on screen) doesn't populate the images. As I start scrolling through the list view, I notice the items that weren't visible earlier, draw the images fine.

Then, if I scroll up [to the items whose images were not drawing] - I see that it has been drawn and set fine.

Have I missed something?

Comment: @darkravedev Did u got any solution

Answer (score 1):

Dont put anything inside the statement if or != exept initialization variables. For exemple :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
View v = convertView;
ScoreHolder holder;

if(v == null){
v = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
holder = new ScoreHolder();
holder.image1 = (SmartImageView) v.find...
v.setTag(holder);
}else{
holder = (ScoreHolder)v.getTag();
}
holder.image1.setImageUrl(urls[position]);
return v;
}
```

Something like that.